# How to prove the following f(x) is convex function

Tags: convex-optimization

1. Verify directly from the definition that the function of one variable f(x) = e^x is convex function.
2. Prove two variables function :f(x1, x2) = x1^2 + 3x2^2 - 3x1x2 + 2x1 is convex

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from the definition, a function $f$ is convex if
$$f(tx + (1 - t) y) \le tf(x) + (1 -t) f(y)$$
for $0 \le t \le 1$. Therefore, for (1), you should directly check that the inequality
$$e^{tx + (1 - t)y} \le te^x + (1 - t)e^y$$
for $0 \le t \le 1$ is true.

For the second part, perhaps you can recall that for smooth functions, there is a certain condition on the second derivative (which is the Hessian, in multiple variables) that guarantees convexity.